# SUID doesn't work in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, suid

I wrote a simple bash script that makes a backup of the home directory, e puts it into /var/backups.
Since that directory is protected, I wrote the script as root, and then set the SUID.

```
armando@ubuntu:~/scripts/bash $ ll
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root    root    2596 Jul 28 10:43 homebackup.sh*
```

Even so, I get the "Permission Denied" error when the scripts tries to write into /var/backups. Why?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/74329

Comment: setuid doesn't work on shell scripts. Use `sudo`, `su` or `perl`.

Comment: @alvits, ...not necessarily even perl, now that `suidperl` is deprecated and withdrawn.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thanks. I didn't know that it has changed.

Comment: For this specific purpose, there is a clever workaround. Create a password locked user with superuser privilege. Register each user's public key as authorized keys of this privileged user. In the authorized_keys, set the command to homebackup.sh script. When a user wants to backup their home directory, all they need is to login as this privilege user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux and most other modern UNIX-family systems, setuid bits are only recognized for direct binary executables, not scripts.

This is by design, and for security reasons. You can work around it by building a compiled wrapper for your setuid scripts, or using an existing tool (such as `sudo` with a configuration to avoid needing a password when calling the specific script as the desired user).

See [this comprehensive discussion on UNIX StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/74329).